# MySQL connector c++ 1.1.3 does not contain libmysql.lib

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2012

So since Saturday I am trying to setup MySQL Connector C++ with VS2012. I'll leave it without commentary that I had to download 1xx mb Boost libs just to run simple query from my program lol. Nevertheless it doesn't work.

The problem is that even when I setup everything correctly (following MySQL Connector Manual from official site) it just can't work - because the [latest package](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/) that I downloaded does not contains files listed in manual. [Manual states](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html):

> Add the lib/opt directory into the Additional Library Directories text field. This enables the library file libmysql.lib to be found.

But there is no libmysql.lib and/or libmysql.dll.

When building I receive obvious error: error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libmysql.lib'

How can I setup this to work correctly?

edit: Maybe someone was setting up VS2012 to work with MySQL Connector C++ lately? Do I need to install MySQL Connector C before? (I've tried, doesn't work). Do I need to install MySQL Server on my comp before (I want to connect to external server anyway).

Comment: anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install MySQL Server (with C/C++ API and libs), the MySQL client library (libmysql.lib) required by MySQL Connector/C++ is in the lib and/or lib/opt directory under the Server installation directory.

Answer (score 1):

The link below will explain you step by step process

```
<
```

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/47548d/install-mysql-connector-in-visual-studio-2012/

http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2010/09/09/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database-from-visual-studio-vs2010-problems-with-net-connectors/
>

Answer (score -1):

1. Do I need to install MySQL Connector C before?

No, they are undepend each other.

1. Do I need to install MySQL Server on my comp before

Yes, you should install MySQL server on your computer, libmysql.dll is in mysql/lib directory.

1. When building I receive obvious error: error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libmysql.lib'

You can for example copy libmysql.dll to c:\windows and linker can find that dll. (or add mysql/lib to PATH envirement varuiable).

P.S. I do only static build, with libmysql.dll, but if you do dynamic build with libmysql.lib file, i think you should do the same things.

Comment: Copying a .dll file doesn't resolve a .lib problem. The linker doesn't use the .dll file. Using libmysql.dll is not a 'static build'. Far too much confusion here. -1

Answer (score -1):

libmysql.* is a part of official mysql connection API

Here:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.0.html

Select the version and download mysql-noinstall-XXX package

/lib/opt /lib/debug contain necessary lib and dll

Add libmysql.lib into project properties->Linker->Input->Additional dependencies like this:

libmysql.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

libmysql.dll should be accessible for an application at run-time as common dll